# Concurrency in linux

Tags: linux, shell, embedded-linux

I am trying to write a small shell script, make it go to sleep for some amount of time like 20 seconds and then run it. Now if i open another terminal and try to run the same script, it shouldn't run as the process is running else where. How do I do it?

I know i should write something, make it go to sleep captures its pid and write a condition that if this pis is running somewhere then don't let it run anywhere. but how do i do it? Please give a code.

```
echo "this is a process"
sleep 60
testfilepid = `ps ax | grep test1.sh | grep -v grep | tr -s " " | cut -f1 -d " "| tail -1`
echo $testfilepid
if [[ $tesfilepid = " " ]]
sh test1.sh
else
echo "this process is already running"
fi
```

This is what I tried. when i execute this in 2 windows, both the windows give me the output this is a process.

Comment: Even small scripts can have indentation. And backticks are outdated; use $(...) instead.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `pgrep` to check that your script/process is running, and negate the output, this is a very basic example that could give you an idea:

```
if ! pgrep -f sleep >/dev/null; then echo "will sleep" && sleep 3; fi
```

Notice the `!`, `pgrep -f sleep` will search for a process matching against full argument lists. (you could customize this to your needs). so if nothing matches your pattern then your script will be called.